# laravel5.1 retrieve not directly related attributes using eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.1, relationship

I've currently no idea how to get this done in a smart way. I would like to prevent writing tons of querys.
First my table design:

```
users:
|id|username|

tickets:
|id|user_id|

ticket_replies:
id|ticket_id|user_id|

files:
|id|ticket_replie_id|name
```

my controllers:

```
user:
public function tickets()
    {
    return $this->hasMany('App\ticket');
    }

ticket:
public function ticket_replie() 
    {
    return $this->hasMany('App\ticket_replie', 'ticket_id', 'id');
}

ticket_replie:
public function file() 
{
        return $this->hasOne('App\File', 'ticket_replie_id', 'id');
}
```

The relation is like following, a user has many tickets. Each ticket has many ticket_replies. A ticket_replie hasOne attachment (file).
Now I need to retrieve the name of a file for a given ticket & ticket_replie_id. 
In my controller I use this at the moment:

```
 $ticket = Auth::user()->tickets()->where('tickets.id', $id)->where('files.ticket_replie_id', $attachment_id)->firstOrFail();
```

Laravel generates me this query & error:

```
select * from `tickets` where `tickets`.`user_id` = 1 and `tickets`.`user_id` is not null and `tickets`.`id` = 43 and `files`.`ticket_replie_id` = 39 limit 1

 Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'files.ticket_replie_id' in 'where clause
```

The query must be something like:

```
select * from `tickets`, `files` where `tickets`.`user_id` = 1 and `tickets`.`user_id` is not null and `tickets`.`id` = 43 and `files`.`ticket_replie_id` = 39 limit 1
```

When I run this query in my database, it returns the needed informations. Is my way to retrieve the information okay? Where's my fault, because at the moment the query generated by Eloquent isn't working as described above.  In case there's a easier way,  just tell me.
It seems like eloquent isn't able to get a relation between ticket and file. How to tell eloquent there's a relation using ticket_replie?

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the `ticket_replie_id` all you have to do is:

```
File::where('ticket_replie_id', $ticket_replie_id)->first();
```

In a more general situation, you would refer to [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Comment: I would like to check, if the user is "allowed" to download this file (without users would be able to "guess" the ids and download files which are not related to them), that's why I would like to use a way with `Auth::user()->tickets()`. Any idea how to do so?

Comment: i would first identify the file and after that check for user permissions